# Multiple JQuery countdowns in a loop with Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm creating a sport app with django. I would like to display a list of matches with a countdown for each match.

For now, I only have one countdown. I use this Jquery countdown: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html (that goes to the new year). I have a loop to display my matches. So the question is how can I insert the countdown into the loop and make it go to the DateTime of my objects "match"?

Here is my template:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">@import "/Users/marc-a   antoine.lacroix/Desktop/Jquery/jquery.countdown.package-1.6.0/jquery.countdown.css";</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.countdown.js">    </script>
<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

var newYear = new Date(); 
newYear = new Date(newYear.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 1); 
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: newYear}); 

});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div style="float:left">
{% for match in matches %}
<div>    
    <p>{{ match }}</p>
    <p> {{match.real_start}} <p>
    <a href="{{ match.get_absolute_url_grille }}">Go</a>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>


<div id="defaultCountdown"> </div>


</body>
```

"matches" is the list containing every matches. "real_start" is the DateTime of my objects "match"

My views.py is simply:

```
 def page(request):
     matches = Match.live_matches.all()

     return render_to_response('myhtml.html', {'matches': matches}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

So I don't know how to import my "real_start" DateTime into the countdown and how to insert this countdown into the loop.

Here is my current code:

```
<script language="javascript">


  $(function(){
  $('.match_wrap').each(function(){
   var match_start=$(this).data('match_start');      
   $(this).find('.matchTimer').countdown({until: match_start});
  });
  })
</script>

</head>
<body>

 <div style="float:left">
 {% for match in matches %}
 </br></br>
 <div class="match_wrap" data-match_start="{{ match.real_start|date:"M j, Y" }}">     
    <p>{{ match }}</p>
    <p> {{match.real_start}} <p>
    <div>
        <ul>
        {% for team in match.teams %}
            <li>
                <img src="{{ team.logo.url }}">
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="{{ match.get_absolute_url_grille }}">Go</a>
    <div class="matchTimer"> </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
</br></br>
```

I also tried:

```
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>


 <script language="javascript">


  $('.match_countdown').each(function() {
  var self = $(this),
    date_string = self.attr('data-date'),
    date = new Date.parse(date_string);
  self.countdown({until: date});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div style="float:left">
{% for match in matches %}
</br></br>
<div class="match_countdown" data-date="{{ match.real_start|date:'M j, Y' }}"></div>  
    <p>{{ match }}</p>
    <p> {{match.real_start}} <p>
    <div>
        <ul>
        {% for team in match.teams %}
            <li>
                <img src="{{ team.logo.url }}">
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="{{ match.get_absolute_url_grille }}">Go</a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to charlietfl's answer but js parses the correct date.

```
{# template #}
{% for match in matches %}
    <div>    
        <p>{{ match }}</p>
        <p> {{match.real_start}} <p>
        <a href="{{ match.get_absolute_url_grille }}">Go</a>
        <div class="match_countdown" data-date="{{ match.real_start|date:'M j, Y' }}"></div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

and then the js:

```
$('.match_countdown').each(function() {
    var self = $(this),
        date_string = self.attr('data-date'),
        date = new Date(date_string);
    self.countdown({until: date});
});
```

Here (http://jsfiddle.net/miki725/MQcYw/1/) js jsfiddle which illustrates the solution.

Comment: Thank you. But when I try your solution there is no countdown appearing anymore.

Comment: Just noticed there was a typo in the div for the `match_countdown`. I had double quotes in Django template filter whereas single quotes were needed. Try now.

Comment: Still nothing. May be I don't do it properly. Is there something I have to change in your code when I paste it into my template?

Comment: Nothing I can think of. Make sure the dates are outputted in html. If HTML is good, then it's a javascript issue.

Comment: I don't have to import anything in order to use "parse"?

Comment: No. Its build in js. What browser are you using? If the issue is js related, maybe it has to do with browser compatibility.

Comment: Could it be that parse only asks Day, Month and Year while DateTime with Django also has hours and seconds?

Comment: I don't think so because `Date.parse` figures out the unix time, which is number of seconds.

Comment: I just edited my question to show you how I try to implement your solution. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. If you see something it would really help me. thank you a lot for your help

Comment: You did not copy exactly my solution. Your `match_counter` is the outer div, whereas it should be inside. Also after I tested it, turns out there were some issues in js. I fixed the answer. Also made jsfiddle to illustrate. http://jsfiddle.net/miki725/MQcYw/1/

Comment: I really don't get it. I copy/paste the code from jsfiddle, and it doesn't work... I'm lost. Could it be because of format of "date"? In  my models date is of this type: YYYY-MM-DD  HH:MM:SS

Comment: Thats what the `|date:'M j, Y'` is for. It formats the date to format js can parse. Make sure everything matches exactly. Usually its the little things.

Comment: OK it works. THANK YOU. The only thing is that the countdown goes to the day I indicate for the match, but not to the exact hour. It doesn't take into account the hour of the match. But I think it's not that hard to solve.

Answer (score 2):

WHenever you need to invoke a plugin on many elements that requires different data for each instance is often easiest to loop over the elements involved and call each instance from within the loop.

Something like this should be easy to implement:

HTML

```
{% for match in matches %}
<div class="match_wrap" data-match_start="{{match.startFormattedToCountDownPlugin}}">    
    <p>{{ match }}</p>
    <p> {{match.real_start}} <p>
    <a href="{{ match.get_absolute_url_grille }}">Go</a>
   </div>
   <div class="matchTimer"> </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

JS

```
$(function(){
   $('.match_wrap').each(function(){
      var match_start=new Date.parse($(this).data('match_start')); 
       $(this).find('.matchTimer').countdown({until: match_start});
   });
})
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I now have a countdown for every matches. But they are stuck to 0. So how can I do so that they go to the "real_start" of my matches? I'm sorry, I'm new with programming and I really have now idea of how to do it.

Comment: Try my solution (Similar to this answer. As I was typing it, @charlierl posted his). It should parse the date correctly into `Date` instance so should work.

Comment: you must pass the properly formatted date to the plugin. Follow the plugin docs. You can either format the date in you django server code, or parse it with javascript. There are lots of tutorials on how to manipulate dates in any language

Comment: Ok, I tried to do it. Now I have countdowns that all indicate the same thing. And I don't know why, they don't go to any real_start of any match. I edited my question to show you what I did. (thank you for your help)

Comment: post a sample of the live html from page source. Structure and date format will be important, as well as making sure you are actually passing dates to the html

Comment: And every time I reload the page, each countdown starts from the exact same value: 33 minutes 47 seconds.

Comment: OK.. I looked at the plugin docs and must pass a javascript date object so use  `var match_start=new Date.parse($(this).data('match_start'));`

Comment: When I do that countdowns do not appear anymore... When I try the solution of miki725, with parse, the same happens.

Comment: again...you need to do some studying of tutorials.. dates are not simple.